# Showing a 'Clear Text' button after detecting the first character in an Input Box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a search bar that allows the user to clear their text if need be. The problem is having the clear button appear after the first keypress. The reverse would happen obviously if no text is present in the input field.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text">
<span>x</span>
```

**CSS**

```
span {cursor: pointer;}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('span').hide();

//Clears the Input Box

$('span').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').val('');
});

//Shows/Hides the Clear Button

$('input[type="text"]').on('focus', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $('span').show();
    } else {
        $('span').hide();
    }
}).blur(function() {
    $('a').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input) to detect when user is interacting with the textbox

```
$('input').on('focus input', function () {
    $('span').toggle(this.value.length>0);
}).blur(function () {
    $('span').hide();
});
```

other option is use type="search" for browsers that support it. Some already add the button and handles this.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hT5uc/1/

Comment: The one reason I didn't use the search attribute for the input is styling issues in css

Comment: "input" event occurs when the text content of an element is changed through the user interface.

Comment: @CarlEdwards Did you try to add the oninput event?

Comment: Seems to do the trick but now I'm having trouble with the function I wrote for clearing the text. The on focus input and that aren't playing nice with each other. I think the reason being that the span is outside of the input box, hence triggering the blur.

Comment: Click fix is to set the click to mousedown

Comment: Not quite understanding what you're saying. Where am I applying the mousedown event in the function?

Comment: change `.click(...)` to `.mousedown(...)`. The mousedown will fire before the blur. Other option is to add a slight delay to the hiding.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/RYY88/

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
    if(($(this).val().length) > 0) {
        $("#clearfix").show();   
    }else {
        $("#clearfix").hide();   
    }
});
```

keyup runs anytime any text is entered or removed from the text box. This allows you to check the length of the entered text to see if any text is entered in.

UPDATE:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z9ygr/1/

```
jQuery('input').bind('input propertychange', function() {
    if(($(this).val().length) > 0) {
         $('span').show();   
    }else {
         $('span').hide(); 
    }
});
```

The updated version will run anytime anything is changed in the textbox. It will run when you paste text in, when you use the keyboard to enter text in.

If your looking for it to ONLY show when the textbox contains TEXT this will work for you.

Comment: You do not need to use the keyboard to add text to an input. Paste with mouse will fail.

Comment: Updated it to handle pasting and keyboard input. (As long as OP only wants to show the clear button when the textbox contains text)